# Private chat with SignalR - talk to strangers

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I would like to write a simple chat on the principle as omegle.com. I wrote that if the user enters the server and the queue is empty creates a new group and falls to the queue. When the other person enters, it connects with this in the queue.
Here's my code:

```
public class UserGroup
{        
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}

public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public static Queue<UserGroup> Users = new Queue<UserGroup>();
    public static string Group { get; set; }

    public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        if(Users.Count == 0)
        {
            var user = new UserGroup { GroupName = Context.ConnectionId };
            Users.Enqueue(user);
            Group = user.GroupName;
            JoinGroup(user.GroupName);

        }
        else
        {
            JoinGroup(Users.Peek().GroupName);
            Group = Users.Peek().GroupName;
            Users.Dequeue();
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public void SayHello(string name, string helloMsg)
    {
        Clients.Caller.Hello(name, helloMsg);

    }

   public void Send(string msg)
    {

        Clients.Group(Group).SendMessage(msg);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, when I connect to someone else, everything breaks down and does not create a new group for new people. All static data, but unfortunately not SignalR allows otherwise. You have an idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a Queue or use groups in this scenario. The easiest solution would be to send the stranger's client id to the other client. You should incorporate locking because you access shared state from different hub instances:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Web Application project and select MVC as framework.
2. Add `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` and `knockoutjs` nuget packages and update all packages.
3. The current SignalR version requires that you add a `Startup` class:

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           app.MapSignalR();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add a hub class:

   ```
   public class ChatHub : Hub
   {
       private static string waitingUser;
       private static readonly object SyncLock = new object();

       public void SendMessage(string text, string clientId)
       {
           this.Clients.Client(clientId).addMessage(text);
       }

       public override Task OnConnected()
       {
           var newUser = this.Context.ConnectionId;
           string otherUser;

           lock (SyncLock)
           {
               if (waitingUser == null)
               {
                   waitingUser = newUser;
                   return base.OnConnected();
               }

               otherUser = waitingUser;
               waitingUser = null;
           }

           this.Clients.Caller.startChat(otherUser);
           this.Clients.Client(otherUser).startChat(newUser);

           return base.OnConnected();
       }
   }
   ```
5. Finally, add the following code to your view:

   ```
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Chat wit a Stranger";
   }

   <h1>Chat with a Stranger</h1>

   <div data-bind="foreach: messages">
       <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
   </div>

   <hr/>

   <form data-bind="submit: send, visible: connected">
       <input type="text" data-bind="value: text" />
       <button type="submit">Send</button>
   </form>

   <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.debug.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
   <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

   <script>

       var hub = $.connection.chatHub;

       var vm = {
           otherUser: "",
           messages: ko.observableArray(["Waiting for a stranger..."]),
           connected: ko.observable(false),
           text: ko.observable(""),

           send: function () {
               var text = vm.text();
               if (text.length == 0) return;
               hub.server.sendMessage(text, vm.otherUser);
               vm.messages.push("You: " + text);
               vm.text("");
           },

           addMessage: function(text) {
               vm.messages.push("Stranger: " + text);
           },

           startChat: function (otherUser) {
               vm.otherUser = otherUser;
               vm.messages(["A stranger has connected. Say hello!"]);
               vm.connected(true);
           }
       }

       ko.applyBindings(vm);

       hub.client.startChat = vm.startChat;
       hub.client.addMessage = vm.addMessage;

       $.connection.hub.start();

   </script>
   ```